# How sub-exponential time does $\text{3SAT}$ have to be to make $\text{NP} \neq\text{EXP}$? What else would imply $\text{NP} \neq\text{EXP}$?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, p-vs-np, 3-sat

The [exponential-time hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Exponential_time_hypothesis) posits that if $\mathsf{3SAT}$ has NO subexponential time algorithm (i.e. one in $\mathcal O(2^{o(n)})$), then $\mathsf{P}\neq \mathsf{NP}$. 
However, I am interested in the case that it does have such an algorithm.

From posts such as [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9237/consequences-of-sub-exponential-proofs-algorithms-for-sat), it seems that simply finding such an algorithm will not prove $\mathsf{NP} \neq\mathsf{EXP}$, so I am wondering just how subexponential the algorithm needs to be in order to guarantee this.

More generally, is there some sort of lists of conjectures/hypotheses that would imply $\mathsf{NP} \neq\mathsf{EXP}$?

Comment: In order to prove that NP$\neq$EXP you would need to find a problem that is in EXP and not in NP, so investigating the complexity of SAT is not a correct approach because it is known to be in both.

Comment: @Laakeri For example, if we know that 3SAT can be solved in $O(n^k)$ time for some k, then clearly $\text{NP}\neq \text{EXP}$. So I'm wondering if there is some intermediate level (between $2^{\log n}$ and $2^n$, say $O(2^{\sqrt n})$ s.t. knowing that 3SAT can be solved in this time implies $\text{NP}\neq \text{EXP}$

Comment: I see, this is by time hierarchy theorem, right? I guess for it to apply you need to have a complexity class that is closed under polynomial-time reductions.

Comment: The first sentence in this post is not an accurate statement of the ETH.

Comment: If there is a $2^{n^{o(1)}}$ algorithm, then the time hierarchy theorem would separate NP from EXP.